# How to retrieve warehouse slots with Shippingbo API?

Tags: api, wms, oms

We are using Shippingbo as WMS

I want to retrieve a list of slots for a specific product

So, I tried to request SlotContent: `https://app.shippingbo.com/slot_contents?search[product_id__eq]=16794293` but it doesn't work

Is any other solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy way to do this, you juste have to request the `warehouse_slots` endpoint

```
curl --request GET \
  --url https://app.shippingbo.com/warehouse_slots?search[product_id__eq][]=21890886 \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'X-API-TOKEN: ' \
  --header 'X-API-USER: ' \
  --header 'X-API-USER-ID: ' \
  --header 'X-API-VERSION: '
```